# How can I pass a value in my input using ShadCN

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a form wherein the user has the ability to choose who are their tech-assistance, is there any way I can add input field when I click the others in my checkbox? I'm using `shadcn` `react-hook-form`[image]

This is my checkbox.

https://pastebin.com/mq5yetND

items.ts

```
const items = [
  {
    id: "tcet",
    label: "TCET",
  },
  {
    id: "others",
    label: "Others",
  },
] as const;
```